# Network Version

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a successfully running network, however I want to change the parameters and deploy the network. I got to know that before deploying the network with changed parameters, I need to change the version of the network in the package file. However I fail to understand to what should I change the network version to for a newly created network?

Please help!.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you should know. A business network has a fixed name which is defined in the `package.json` located in your folder where the smart contract is defined. To upgrade a chaincode the name should remain the exact same while the version should increase.

Let's assume your file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "my-special-network",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  .........

}
```

Now lets say the first iteration was made using `1.0.0` as the version. The commands would look something like

```
cd chaincode
composer archive create -t dir -n .
composer network install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a my-special-network@1.0.0.bna
composer network start --networkName my-special-network --networkVersion 1.0.0 -A admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network
```

So the above would create a bna file based on the version in the package.json. For consistency, while starting the network we passed the same value as the `--networkVersion` variable. Now some new features were added and an updated version needs to be added. Your new package.json would be

```
{
  "name": "my-special-network",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  .........

}
```

The version should be greater than `1.0.0` while the `name` has to be exactly the same. The new set of commands would be

```
cd chaincode
composer archive create -t dir -n .
composer network install -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network -a my-special-network@1.0.1.bna
composer network upgrade--networkName my-special-network --networkVersion 1.0.1 -c PeerAdmin@fabric-network
```

Notice the command start is changed to upgrade, while the admin secret is no longer passed. If you check `docker image ls` the chaincode image for the previous version will exist. I find it  good practice to delete it.